# Options in multiple rows in document class exam

Tags: exam, examdesign

In document class exam, is there any way to write options in 2 rows in oneparchoices or choices  environment as in the image below? I tried using multicols but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: You could use the `tasks` package and replace `\begin{choices}` and `\end{choices}` with `\begin{tasks}(2)` and `\end{tasks}` and `\choice` with `\task`.

Comment: @leandriis Thank You. It worked. You may post it as the answer so that I can upvote it.

Comment: @leandriis The options are written as a), b), c), d). It there anyway they can be written as (a), (b),(c), (d)?

Comment: The `tasks` package  offers the possibility to control the label to suit your needs. Take a look at the `label` option. If you add the left parenthesis, you may also need to adjust the value of `label-width` to account for the extra width of the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the tasks package and replace `\begin{choices}` and `\end{choices}` with `\begin{tasks}(2)` and `\end{tasks}` and `\choice` with `\task`.

To change the label style to suit your needs, you may want to use the `label` option.
Something like `\settasks{label=(\alph*), label-width=1.5em}` in the preamble of the document should result in the expected output.

Comment: Is there any **correctchoice** type option in task so that when when I use **printanswers** command, it highlights the correct answer is some specific color?